# How to read kernel messages from screan at boot time, in case boot crashes?

Tags: hardware, boot, kernel

How can I read the messages of kernel page by page on the screan at the boot time ? I know the "dmesg" command or /var/log ... but my box crashes before booting could have finished. Is there any option of vmlinuz or grub to stop its messages page by page on the screen at boot time? (I removed the boot parameters of kernel: "quiet splash", so I have a lots of msg on the screan. But the rows run away quickly.)